# JSON object becomes null in struts action class

Tags: json, class, struts, struts-action

i am working in struts 1.3 , i am constructing the json object into javascript and passing JSON object to my struts action class but when i receive json it is comming null here is my sample code

```
 var dataobj=[{code:c1,name:n1}];

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "addtier.do",
dataType: "json"
data: "data?="+dataobj;
});
```

action class code

```
 JSONObject jObj    = new JSONObject();
 JSONObject newObj = jObj.getJSONObject(request.getParameter("data"));
 Enumeration eNames = newObj.keys(); //gets all the keys

 while(eNames.hasNextElement())
 {
     // Here I need to retrieve the values of the JSON string
     // and add it to the session
 }
```

this line is coming null

```
request.getParameter("data");
```

and when parse it is giving exception

```
 JSONObject newObj = jObj.getJSONObject(request.getParameter("data"));
```

what actually iam doing wrong. this i am not understanding
is my json data is in wrong format or some thing else
any hint would be of my great help

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataobj=[{code:c1,name:n1}];

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "addtier.do",
dataType: "json"
data: dataobj;
});
```

Seems like you are setting the data parameter to `data?=[Object]`.

Try `console.log('data?='+dataobj);` and you will see what i mean.

If you are supposed to supply it with a string and not a jaon object then you will want to `JSON.stringify(dataobj)` first.

Also another issue is that it may be required to send a json object and not a json array, so of it still doesnt work try making sure dataobj is: `{data:[{key:"val",key2:"val2"}]}`

Comment: if i want that json object to post as string then i will have to do like this JSON.stringify(dataobj) $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "addtier.do",
dataType: "text"
data: JSON.stringify(dataobj);
}); will this works as i am very new ajax and json

Answer (score 0):

You could use this :

```
String jsonData = request.getReader().readLine();
```

Instead of this :

```
String jsonData = request.getParameter("data");
```

Note : use a POST send(jsonData) in Javascript